# Google analytics hasn't been working for a few days

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

In each page in the `<head>` I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javacript">
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-aaa-bbb', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

It's been 2 days already with no sessions and in Chrome developer panel there's no traffic being sent to google analytics when I open my website and trace the requests in Chrome. In the dashboard everything is setup correctly.

update:

2 errors:

1) `No HTTP response detected`
2) `Missing analytics.js script`

Why would I need analytics.js?

Comment: Do you have any filters set up that may be blocking your traffic? Also check with Tag assistant to see if any issues with your tracking code.

Comment: You've got 6 parameters but you're passing only 5. Any reason you're obfuscating this code but leaving the analytics URL in plaintext?

Comment: Try accessing your website as a legit user and debug that page. Can you see your analytics code at the end your page now?

Comment: @Mario, that's the generated code.

Comment: Hm, OK. Haven't used analytics in ages.

Comment: @nyuen, see my update.

Comment: Why would you need analytics.js? It is the JavaScript library that contains all you need to track anything and everything for Google analytics.

Comment: @nyuen, I mean locally.

Comment: Try fixing your script type as you have a typo. Should be `javascript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your script attribute:

```
<script type="text/javacript">
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```